# Detecting people from above with opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, detection

I am using the HOG descriptor, with the default people detector from opencv in python to try detecting people from above. The camera is positioned over a corridor and the descriptor from opencv doesn't have a very good performance, since it doesn't detect people very well and sometimes tracks some painings on the walls. Can anyone help me in understanding how to improve the performace?

Comment: it was trained on ppl from front/back/side, not from above, so it cant detect those. (same problem with the daimler detector)

Comment: Any suggestion on how can I obtain do this?

Comment: @Neskelogth You will have to train your own classifier

Comment: Train your own HoG or, maybe better, a (tiny) yolo v3/v4 DNN, which might outperform HoG in every property.